# To get id of the data in autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery

I am using autocomplete in my form. Iam getting the vessel_name from the table vessel. But i need both vessel_name and vessel_id from the table vessel.I need vessel_id to insert the data in another table fixture.

```
<input type="text" id="vessel_name" placeholder="Vessel Name" class="form-control" name="nam">
 <input type="hidden" id="vessel_id" class="form-control" name="id">



    <script>
             $(function() {
                 var availableTags = <?php include('vname.php'); ?>;
                      $("#vessel_name").autocomplete({
                           source: availableTags,
                           autoFocus:true,
                           minLength:2
                      });
              });
    </script>
```

vname.php

```
<?php
            $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vasishipping")or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

           //fetch vessel names from the vessel table
           $sql = "select * from vessel";
           $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error " .mysqli_error($connection));

           $dname_list = array();
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
              $vname_list[] = $row['vessel_name'];
              $vname_list[] = $row['vessel_id'];
          }
          echo json_encode($vname_list);
?>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, but I would suggest removing `$vname_list[] = $row['vessel_name'];` and 
`$vname_list[] = $row['vessel_id'];` and replace those two lines with `$vname_list[] = array("name"=>$row['vessel_name'], "id"=>$row['vessel_id']);`

Comment: hello @Matt, I need the vessel_id to be stored in the hidden tag. I need to store the input data with respect to vessel_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that your `availableTags` is a 1-dimentional array.
You can transform that array into a object array, with a key and a value:

```
var availableTags = [
  { key: "1", value: "ActionScript" },
  { key: "2", value: "AppleScript" },
  { key: "3", value: "Asp" }
];
```

And retrieve the values adding a select function to the autocomplete options:

```
$("#vessel_name").autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  autoFocus:true,
  minLength:2,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $("#vessel_name").val(ui.item.value);
    $("#vessel_id").val(ui.item.key);
  }
});
```

Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/uzq89nf6/) retrieving both values

**Edit: adding the PHP changes to retrieve the `availableTags` array on the right format**

The PHP part should be changed to provide the JSON on the example format.
Just add this on your while loop:

```
$vname = $row['vessel_name'];
$vid = $row['vessel_id'];
$variable[] = array( 'key' => "$vid", 'value' => "$vname" )
```

and return `$variable` to `json_encode`

Comment: Hello Auro, i need vessel_name and Vessel_id values from database. How can i get it in key value pair. You have set the data fixed, but i need data dynamically from database.

Comment: I've edited the answer with what should be changed on the php